# selecting items from a list with linq, where items appear in other two lists

Tags: linq, contains, where-clause, any

i have two lists which contains guids:

```
    var activeSoftware = channels.ByPath("/software/").Children.Where(c => c.StateProperties.IsActive).Select(c => c.Guid);
    var activeChannels = channels.ByPath("/game-channels/").Children.Where(c => c.StateProperties.IsActive).Select(c => c.Guid);
```

and another list, of games:

`List<MyCms.Content.Games.Game> games = new List<MyCms.Content.Games.Game>();`

the game object has two properties that can use:

`game.gamingproperties.software` - which contains the guid of the software
`game.stateproperties.channels` - a list of comma seperated guids

yes, i know its not good to save comma seperated values in a field,
but i cannot change it at this point of time ( its allready working on 40+ sites )

what i want to do, is select all games where the software is active ( by comparing `softwarelist` to the `game.gamingproperties.software` ) and that the channels they appear in is active ( by checking if `game.stateproperties.channels` contains any of `activechannels` guids )

originally, i have done this like so:

```
    foreach (var channel in activeSoftware)
    {
        foreach (var match in oGames.AllActive.Where(g => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(g.GamingProperties.UrlDirectGame) && g.GamingProperties.Software.Contains(channel) && g.StateProperties.Channels.Split(',').Intersect(activeChannels).Any()))
        {
            games.Add(match);
        }
    }
```

but i am sure i can get rid of those nasty foreach and just use linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object model does look a little odd, so I think it could be refactored somewhat, but here's my answer:

```
var query =
    from channel in activeSoftware
    from match in oGames.AllActive
    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.GamingProperties.UrlDirectGame)
    where match.GamingProperties.Software.Contains(channel)
    where match.StateProperties.Channels.Split(',').Intersect(activeChannels).Any()
    select match;

var games = query.ToList();
```

You could also do this, if I understand your model correctly:

```
var query =
    from match in oGames.AllActive
    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.GamingProperties.UrlDirectGame)
    where match.GamingProperties.Software.Intersect(activeSoftware).Any()
    where match.StateProperties.Channels.Split(',').Intersect(activeChannels).Any()
    select match;

var games = query.ToList();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: how come you think the object model is a little odd?

Comment: Just the `match.GamingProperties.Software` & `match.StateProperties.Channels` seem a little long-winded and not very clear as to their purpose. I had to provide my answer on faith to a degree.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your solution could use some refactoring... but here's something rough to give you the idea.

```
var new items = items.ForEach(channel => 
from g in oGames.AllActive
where (.Where(g => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(g.GamingProperties.UrlDirectGame) && g.GamingProperties.Software.Contains(channel) && g.StateProperties.Channels.Split(',')
     .Intersect(activeChannels).Any())))    
 games.add(items);
```

please post class definitions if you'd like me to be more specific.